# Nginx to proxy_pass request and pass back the response

Tags: linux, nginx, proxypass

I've been struggling with setting up nginx as a reverse proxy.

What I want to achieve is:

1. **Server 1** sends a POST request to: http://1.2.3.4:60009/pass (**NGINX server**)
2. the **NGINX Server** passes it on to **Server 2**: http://1.12.13.14:60009/destination/
3. **Server 2** sends a response through the NGINX server back to **Server 1**.

Right now the request gets passed through to the end destination but the response doesn't go anywhere.

Here is my site configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 60009;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/60009_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/60009_error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /pass {
        proxy_pass http://1.12.13.14:60009/destination/;
        proxy_read_timeout 1200;
    }
}
```

I currently get a 499 error by NGINX.

The servers work with asynchronous requests. Server 1 sends out a connection request, gets proxy_passed by my nginx server and ends at Server 2. Server 2 accepts the request and sends back an acknowledgment response which ends nowhere.

I tried searching for similar problems or solutions, but I couldn't find much. If I'm using the wrong terminology please let me know so that I can correct myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410932/6450889 the error code signifies a timeout. I would guess your back-end might take to long to respond or behaves in a non-standard way.

Also, if you haven't done this already, verify the request arrive at your backend (Server 2).

Comment: Hey c11o, thanks for making an account and replying! I can verify that the request does arrive at Server 2.

Comment: I was not aware you have three servers at play, I mistakenly changed "sent" to "receive", assuming Server 1 is the one running your nginx.
Is there a particular reason for a timeout of 20 minutes (1200 seconds)?

Comment: No specific reason! This is how it was configured when I started working on this project